# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/(my App ID):clientId,setScreenName

Tags: ios, admob

I attempted to upload my app to the App Store today and received this warning.

> The app references non-public selectors in Payload/(my App ID):clientId,setScreenName

I searched this warning on Google and most of the answers pointed to third-party SDK's. There is only one third-party SDK in my application, `GoogleMobileAds`. So I remove `GoogleMobileAds` from my app and no warning message appears. I am confused, does this mean I can't use `GoogleMobileAds` my app? I've used `GoogleMobileAds` in apps I've wrote before and never received this warning.

Answer (score 2):

AdMob 7.2.2 is out now with a fix.

> Fixes the following warning when uploading to the App Store:  The app
>   references non-public selectors in
>   Payload/():clientId,screenName,setScreenName.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this warning for using a selector in your own code or third-party SDK that has the same name as a selector that is marked as non-public. Make sure you are using the latest [AdMob SDK](http://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download).

Update: This issue has been fixed in [AdMob 7.2.2](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/rel-notes#ios)

> Fixes the following warning when uploading to the App Store: The app
>   references non-public selectors in
>   Payload/():clientId,screenName,setScreenName.

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded to GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.2.1 SDK and we were rejected by Apple for the non-public selectors: clientId, screenName, setScreenName.

Comment: will an older version pass?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the new version 7.2.2 and replace the old framework with the new one..!! And Sit Back And Enjoy..!!